# How stop insert action in trigger

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle Apex. 
I need to create a trigger for checking the no. of stock whether < 0. 
If the no. of stock < 0 then insert action is stopped then prompt a alert message to user.
Below coding dose not work. what is wrong of my code? please help.

My coding:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cw_service_b4_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON cw_serviceline
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

 exist_stock number;

BEGIN
    select stock into exist_stock from cw_inventory where inv_id = :new.inv_id;
       if (exist_stock - :new.quantity) < 0 then
         dbms_output.put_line ('Out of Stock');
         return;
       end if;
END;
/
```

Comment: Please expand on 'does not work'. Do you have an error (post it) or does it do nothing (explain what you expect)

Comment: The quantity column of cw_inventory table is configured no allowing < 0. when i press apply change on APEX. show below message:1 error has occurred
ORA-02290: check constraint (LECTURE_6.CH_STOCK) violated ORA-06512: at "LECTURE_6.CW_INVENTORY_SERVICE_TRIGGER", line 3 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'LECTURE_6.CW_INVENTORY_SERVICE_TRIGGER' (Row 3). It seems to attempt to insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't thrown any sort of error. All your trigger does is output a message.

`return` doesn't cause the INSERT to stop, it just causes the trigger logic to return.

Instead you need to raise an error to cause the insert to fail.

```
if exist_stock < :new.quantity then
    raise_application_error(-20000, 'Out of stock'); 
end if;
```